# Change the schema of table while restoring the database from bacpac file?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, bacpac

I have a **bacpac** file which I generated from SQL Server. And now, I am restoring the database using this **bacpac** file into the Azure Managed Instance.

Here, I am trying to change the schema of the table according to the requirement.
The question is, can I change the schema of tables while restoring the database into Azure Managed Instance?

For instance, I have 10 tables having the schema `sales` and I want to change the schema to `currentSales`.

Answer (score 0):

I know of no way to automate it as part of the bacpac process but if you truly only have a few Tables then you can script out a [schema `TRANSFER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-schema-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) for each of them like so:

```
ALTER SCHEMA currentSales TRANSFER sales.Table1;
ALTER SCHEMA currentSales TRANSFER sales.Table2;
ALTER SCHEMA currentSales TRANSFER sales.Table3;
ALTER SCHEMA currentSales TRANSFER sales.Table4;
ALTER SCHEMA currentSales TRANSFER sales.Table5;
ALTER SCHEMA currentSales TRANSFER sales.Table6;
ALTER SCHEMA currentSales TRANSFER sales.Table7;
ALTER SCHEMA currentSales TRANSFER sales.Table8;
ALTER SCHEMA currentSales TRANSFER sales.Table9;
ALTER SCHEMA currentSales TRANSFER sales.Table10;
```

Please keep in mind this transfers those Tables **only** and does not update any references to those Tables inside other database objects such as Views or Stored Procedures. Those would need to be manually altered, if you are using any that reference these procedures.